# React: can I pass hook in component prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it ok to pass hook in component prop? Example:

```
const Example = ({ useData }) => {
  const { data, loading } = useData();
  
  return <>{data}</>
}
```

The use case I have is something like this:

```
const ToggleDisplay = ({ useData }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setShow(value => !value)}>Toggle</button>
    {show && {<ToggleItem useData={useData} />}
  </>
}

const ToggleItem = ({ useData }) => {
  const { data, loading } = useData();

  return <>{data}</>
}
```

where useData may be a different hook responsible for fetch different data.

Comment: Where do you pass a React hook in your use case snippet? React hooks are *just* functions with special rules in naming convention and use within React.

Comment: @DrewReese now I added the hook passing in use case example

Comment: Sure. Looks valid to me in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's completely valid. Your useData hook is simply a function that you would be passing into your `<ToggleItem />` function component as a prop.